# Gods and their current life style

Tags: scripture, gods, life

Just want to ask simple clear things.

In Hinduism, we have lots of life stories for all gods, whether it's Rama, or Krishna, or Vishnu or even Mahadev.

like we know

- Birth of Gajanand
- Race between Kartikeya with Ganapati
- Who is bigger among all tridev.

or many more, countless.

I know that they are written in vaidic yug by our enchanters like Ved vayas or tulsidas or from four vedas.

**My question :**

- Where are our gods now?
- What are they doing now, at present time?

> because I know that our gods are immortal, and as they are immortal, they are somewhere and doing something....

I don't want exact answer, just asking if this is written somewhere...

Comment: not elaborating anything but if you relax, focus, concentrate & meditate you'll figure out that everything is within you.

Comment: @Just_Do_It well, I am doing it from last many years, but I like to ask entertaining questions..

Comment: did you make any real progress?

Comment: well, honestly not enough, my schedule is tight, so can't give proper time for meditation..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gods are in same place where they were earlier. But the thing which we lost today is not gods but Great Narrators(Mahaa Rishis) who could describe us current activities of Gods.
Earlier Great sages had divya drishti by which they were able to see whole universe. They were mentally attached with Gods. Whatever Incidents happens with Gods, they got aware of it immediately. They could feel
God's every activities because of their great devotion and penance(which is missing in today's time). 
Today, no one(probably) is capable enough that have linked his soul with Gods. That's why They are not aware what Gods is doing right now.

Earlier the sages could wrote about Gods because they could see all their activities by their own eyes, hence they wrote it. But no one can do this in today's time because we are so much
involved in worldly items instead of devotion. Today, no one on Earth has left that can tell us what God is doing right now unlike earlier time where lots of great sages were their to tell us all.

Long story short, One need to done enough penance that can link his soul with God then he will became aware of Gods activities, living style and everything else. And after knowing it, he can tell us. But who can do this in today's time? May be No one..

Answer (score 3):

If you believe in the Adviata principle the same God dwells in you, in me, and in all of us. This is a tremendous truth.. that even entertains sometimes..